# Converting SQL ON Clause to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm not sure exactly how to convert this SQL to LINQ:

```
LEFT JOIN pppltd.dbo.weboeordd ON pppltd.dbo.WEBOEORDD.ITEMNO = REPLACE(datawarehouse.dbo.ORDERFORMDUMP.ITEMNO,'-','') and weboeordd.ORDUNIQ = weboeordh.orduniq
```

This is the LINQ I have:

```
join weboeordd in db.WebOEOrdD on item.ITEMNO.Replace("-", "") equals weboeordd.ITEMNO && weboeordd.ORDUNIQ == db.WebOEOrdH.ORDUNIQ
```

The compiler is giving me an error on the right side of the "**==**" operator saying that "WebOEOrdH" doesn't have a definition for ORDUNIQ, but I know it does in the model.

**UPDATE**

Ivan Stoev has been kind enough to leave a link from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx) on joins using composite keys

As a result, I've changed my LINQ to use anonymous types:

```
join weboeordd in db.WebOEOrdD on new { itemno = item.ITEMNO.Replace("-", ""), orduniq = weboeordh.ORDUNIQ } equals new { itemno = weboeordd.ITEMNO, orduniq = weboeordd.ORDUNIQ }
```

Comment: Could you show us the whole linq statement?

Comment: [How to: Join by Using Composite Keys (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx)

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you! That link really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivan Stoev has been kind enough to leave a link from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx) on joins using composite keys

As a result, I've changed my LINQ to use anonymous types:

```
join weboeordd in db.WebOEOrdD on new { itemno = item.ITEMNO.Replace("-", ""), orduniq = weboeordh.ORDUNIQ } equals new { itemno = weboeordd.ITEMNO, orduniq = weboeordd.ORDUNIQ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use `equals` LINQ operator instead of `==` comparison operator. See MSDN for [join clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

Comment: I already have an equals keyword in the LINQ query to join the two tables on ITEMNO, but in SQL, anything you write after an ON clause is like a WHERE clause. You can't really use the equals keyword twice in a query, so that's why I was using the == comparison operator.